# Shifting of entire body

Tags: html, css

I'm sure some of you have seen it before, but it happened twice to me before and just now another time. Sometimes when I navigate on my site, the entire body shifts like 2 or 3 pixels to the left or the right. Although the CSS and code isn't changing...

Has anyone an idea where this behavior comes from? Or how to solve this? (I can't paste code, since it's a very large and complex website, and pasting this mass here would bother most of you guys :)

Comment: what is the link to your website?

Comment: It's still under development... I can try and deploy something within a few hours...

Comment: I think I can speak for myself as well as several others when I say I've never experienced this before. We can't really help you without seeing some code...if you can, post the code that you feel is relevant to the issue.

Comment: Post only the snippet of code necessary to reproduce the described behavior. You're right; we don't want to see all the code for your entire website. Just a small, self-contained demo.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the comments. I'll paste a snippet when I have access to it (I'm behind a proxy right now which blocks private fpt's, so...) It should be online around 8pm (GMT +1)

Answer (score 2):

Bet it's the scrollbar either being there or not.

To get round that, force it always to show one by adding `overflow-y:scroll;` to your `html` tag.

(Edit: my brain broke)

Comment: Good chance it is indeed! I'll check when I get home! Thanks!

Comment: I would agree but he said "2 or 3 pixels".

Comment: Yeah, I know, but maybe he was just guessing. If it's not this, then we'll need to see some code.

Answer (score 0):

this usually occurs when the body height is less then the window height. so you can do it by adding overflow:scroll; in css